# Why does hadoop in Windows7 raised a RuntimeException: Error in configuring object

Tags: python, hadoop, windows-7, hadoop-streaming, runtimeexception

I'm trying to run a hadoop program in pseudo-distributed mode in windows7, and a RuntimeException has been raised. I don't know why and how to fix it.

I use python for mapreduce work instead of java using hadoop-streaming utility(https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html). I ran `hadoop jar %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\tools\lib\hadoop-streaming-2.6.2.jar -mapper mapper.py -reducer reducer.py -input myinput -output myoutput -file mapper.py -file reducer.py` and a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object` has been raised and job failed.

My hadoop version is 2.6.2, and hadoop is built on windows7 x64, not on virtual machine or cygwin.

First of all, I used the standard test program of hadoop to test whether hadoop is installed successfully. I ran `yarn jar %HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.2.jar pi 16 1000` and the output is correct. Hadoop and MapReduce work.

Secondly, the mapper.py and reducer.py have been tested under command prompt using command `cat data.txt | python mapper.py | sort | python reducer.py` and the output is correct. Thus, it wouldn't be the python program's bug.

I try to change the 'hadoop.tmp.dir' property to local directory and /tmp, but neither worked. 
I don't know why the exception was raised and how to fix it. Thanks a lot if anyone can help me!

The complete Exception log is as follows:

```
16/03/25 18:47:46 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use generic option -files instead.
packageJobJar: [mapper.py, reducer.py, /C:/Users/chensk/AppData/Local/Temp/hadoop-unjar5079915111177028733/] [] C:\Users\chensk\AppData\Local\Temp\streamjob6081649198401076264.jar tmpDir=null
16/03/25 18:47:47 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/03/25 18:47:48 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/03/25 18:47:50 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/03/25 18:47:50 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
16/03/25 18:47:50 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1458902651843_0002
16/03/25 18:47:51 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1458902651843_0002
16/03/25 18:47:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://skyfalls:8088/proxy/application_1458902651843_0002/
16/03/25 18:47:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1458902651843_0002
16/03/25 18:47:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1458902651843_0002 running in uber mode : false
16/03/25 18:47:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/03/25 18:48:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1458902651843_0002_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "G:\Programs\hadoop\tmp\nm-local-dir\usercache\chensk\appcache\application_1458902651843_0002\container_1458902651843_0002_01_000003\.\mapper.py": CreateProcess error=193, %1 ??????完?? Win32 ??車
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 ??????完?? Win32 ??車
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more

16/03/25 18:48:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
16/03/25 18:48:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1458902651843_0002_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "G:\Programs\hadoop\tmp\nm-local-dir\usercache\chensk\appcache\application_1458902651843_0002\container_1458902651843_0002_01_000002\.\mapper.py": CreateProcess error=193, %1 ??????完?? Win32 ??車
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 ??????完?? Win32 ??車
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more

16/03/25 18:48:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/03/25 18:48:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1458902651843_0002_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "G:\Programs\hadoop\tmp\nm-local-dir\usercache\chensk\appcache\application_1458902651843_0002\container_1458902651843_0002_01_000004\.\mapper.py": CreateProcess error=193, %1 ??????完?? Win32 ??車
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 ??????完?? Win32 ??車
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more

16/03/25 18:48:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1458902651843_0002_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "G:\Programs\hadoop\tmp\nm-local-dir\usercache\chensk\appcache\application_1458902651843_0002\container_1458902651843_0002_01_000005\.\mapper.py": CreateProcess error=193, %1 ??????完?? Win32 ??車
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 ??????完?? Win32 ??車
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more

16/03/25 18:48:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1458902651843_0002_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "G:\Programs\hadoop\tmp\nm-local-dir\usercache\chensk\appcache\application_1458902651843_0002\container_1458902651843_0002_01_000006\.\mapper.py": CreateProcess error=193, %1 ??????完?? Win32 ??車
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 ??????完?? Win32 ??車
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more

16/03/25 18:48:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1458902651843_0002_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "G:\Programs\hadoop\tmp\nm-local-dir\usercache\chensk\appcache\application_1458902651843_0002\container_1458902651843_0002_01_000007\.\mapper.py": CreateProcess error=193, %1 ??????完?? Win32 ??車
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 ??????完?? Win32 ??車
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more

16/03/25 18:48:32 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/03/25 18:48:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1458902651843_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1458902651843_0002_m_000001
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

16/03/25 18:48:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 13
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=7
        Killed map tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=8
        Other local map tasks=6
        Data-local map tasks=2
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=52274
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=52274
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=52274
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=53528576
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
16/03/25 18:48:34 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful!
Streaming Command Failed!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of the `-mapper` and `-reducer` command-line arguments need be executables.  On Windows, which doesn't support shebang lines, Python scripts aren't executable.

Try specifying the `-mapper` and `-reducer` arguments as follows:

```
-mapper "python mapper.py" -reducer "python reducer.py"
```

Please note that I haven't run this myself so I can't guarantee that it will work.  It may complain that it can't find a file whose name is `python mapper.py`.

If this doesn't work, write short batch scripts `mapper.bat` and `reducer.bat` that just run the corresponding Python script.  For example, `mapper.bat` would contain the following lines:

```
@echo off
python mapper.py %*
```

Then, specify these batch scripts as your `-mapper` and `-reducer` arguments.  Also, add the command-line arguments `-file mapper.bat` and `-file reducer.bat` to ensure that these batch scripts get copied to all your compute nodes.

Comment: I try to specify the -mapper and -reducer arguments as `python mapper.py` and `python reducer.py`, and that works!  Thanks a lot!